# How to know when the language has changed?

Tags: hooks

I need to know when the language change in the site, because I need to performs some actions in this moment, I searched in the docs for a hook to perform this action (in my case this is the best option or at least this is what I think) but I can't find any hook related.

The language can be changed with the language switcher links or not and this need to be trigger for roles with some defined permissions.

I need this for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Comment: What do you mean by language changed? The language switcher links to the same page in another language. You need for anonymous traffic probably a session to detect this.

Comment: @4k4 if you're in the english version of the site and you change to the spanish version for example.

Comment: by using the language switcher and for anonymous traffic?

Comment: @4k4 can be using the language switcher or not, and for users with some permissions.

Comment: For logged in users you have a session anyway. Then you can set the language in a session variable and check if it has changed.

Comment: @4k4 so, there is not hook for this?

Comment: No (the full list of hooks is here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Language%21language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/8.2.x). For such a hook to exist you'd have to start tracking people's movements around the site. Someone landing on a Spanish page from Google would not need the hook to be invoked, someone landing on the same page from an English page on the same site would. It would get messy quickly

Comment: You could track this using a cookie.